# Progressbar com steps posição fica errada

Tags: android, xml, progress-bar

Estou tendo problemas para deixar na posição correta do fluxo com o progresso  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/checkout_hsv_scrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lineFluxos"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">


            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Adiciono dinamicamente  as imagens pois o fluxo pode ter até mais de 3

```
   int fluxosAutorizadosCount = 0;
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.weight = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < fluxoList.size(); i++) {
            ImageView image = new ImageView(getActivity());

            if (fluxosAutorizadosCount < pedido.getFluxosAutorizados().size()) {
                fluxosAutorizadosCount++;
                image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_check_circle));

            } else {
                image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_check_done));
            }
            image.setLayoutParams(lp);
            lineFluxos.addView(image);

        }

        progressBar.setProgress((fluxosAutorizadosCount * 100) / fluxoList.size());
```

Comment: Pelo que vejo parece-me desfasamento entre o valor da progress e de onde os checks estão posicionados. Nesse exemplo a progress marca 67% que está certo para dois checks, mas como o check está a meio do bloco entre 33% e 67% fica desalinhado. Pode tentar alinhar isso colocando ele a meio do bloco colocando na progress `67 - ((100 / 3 ) / 2)`, que é basicamente `valorProgress - ((100 / quantidadeChecks) / 2)`. Naturalmente se tiver alterado os limites da progress precisa de ser `valorProgress - (((progMax - progMin) / quantidadeChecks) / 2)`